# JBoss refuses to run as Install4j service due to earlier logging configuration

Tags: jboss, install4j

I am trying to use Install4j's Service Launcher to deploy a bundled JBoss EAP 6.1 with our application.  JBoss is refusing to start because:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
```

I already have this java.util.logging.manager system property set but I believe Install4j's wrapper is somehow initializing a JRE-wide logging facility prior to JBoss getting a chance.  So JBoss just refuses to run.

Please see [this JBoss issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1547) where users with the TanukiSoftware wrapper face a similar problem. Is there any way of disabling this earlier initialization in the Install4j service launcher so that JBoss will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In install4j 5.1.8, there will be a system property "install4j.noLoggingFix" that prevents the initialization of the logging system. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get an interim build with this feature.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I implemented a fix for his problem, how does that not answer the question?

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks Ingo.  I will do that.  This answers my question exactly.  Unfortunately, I can't upvote yet as I'm too new.  Thanks again.